# "In some numbers, digits are distinct" What does it mean?

Tags: combinatorics

> Form 4 digit numbers using $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$
>   a) In some of the numbers, digits are distinct.
>   b) The number is even.
>   Solve for just $a$, just $b$, and for both $a$ and $b$.

I could not understand what is meant in part $a$. Is not it same with the set of all $4$ digit numbers written with $\{1,2,3,4,5\} = 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 5$?

Comment: I take it to mean, there are a lot of $4$-digit numbers you can form from $1,2,3,4,5$; some of them use the same digit more than once (for example, 1231), and some of them don't (for example, 4153); we want the ones that don't.

Comment: @gnometorule it is the combinatorics class and we are currently only considering integer numbers. but I could not understand the meaning of the "some" either.

Answer (score 1):

$(a)$ asks you to find $4$-digit numbers with digits in $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ for which the digits are distinct, i.e. 1234 or 3245, and $(b)$ wants you to find even $4$-digit numbers with digits in $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, i.e. 2344 or 5432.  Then it wants you to find even 4-digit numbers with distinct digits, i.e. 5412.

Comment: But then, what is the use of the word "some"? Some does not mean all, right?

Comment: Well, I guess it could mean to form sets of them that have at least one number with distinct digits.

Comment: @alev Oh- here's an idea.  Maybe *some* should be *sum*- so it would mean to form $4$-digit numbers for which the sum of the digits has distinct digits.

Comment: I do no have an idea. Instructor wrote it without looking to a book. It was the first question of the lecture and I guess he underestimated this question and did not even want to waste time with question and gave it as a homework.

Comment: @alev Perhaps you should email him and ask.

Comment: you are right. I thought it could have a special meaning. But seems like it does not. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Solution for (just a): 5*4*3*2 = 5! = 120
Solution for (just b): 5*5*5*2 = 250 (Numbers may not be distinct)
Solution for (both a and b): 4*3*2*2 = 48 (Numbers are distinct digit and even)